# How to keep user logged in between page refreshes in Flask and React

Tags: reactjs, flask

I have a React frontend connected to a Flask backend. I am trying to get a user logged in using react-google-login. I am currently sending the response token to the backend to be verified and to log in the user.

```
fetch('/login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          token: response.accessToken
       })
      })
```

I am saving the token in the backend as `session['token']`. Then in my parent App component I make a call to the backend to check if `len(session) == 0` to see if the user is logged in.

```
@app.route('/_loggedin')
def loggedin():
    if len(session) == 0:
        return {'isLogged': False}
    return {'isLogged': True}

@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    content = request.get_json()
    session['token'] = content['token']
    return {'status': 0}
```

This changes the state to indicate that the user is logged in and authorizes a private route.

```
function App() {
    const [authed, setAuthed] = useState();
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('/_loggedin').then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
          setAuthed(data.isLogged);
        });
      }, []);
    return(
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/login">
                    <Login />
                </Route>
                <PrivateRoute authed={authed} path='/' component={Home} />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    );
};
```

All of this works so far but when I refresh the page, it seems to forget the session. Can anyone advise on a better strategy for this log in process or what is going wrong here?

Comment: Hey did you ever end up figuring this out? @jzm5

Answer (score 0):

A state in react is not persistent I.e, everything will go away when you  refresh the page. What you need to do is persist the data in something like local storage or cookies.

Comment: Shouldn't my frontend be fetching _loggedin and the Flask session variable should persist between sessions. Or is each reload first resetting authed without calling the _loggedin?

Comment: hello, did you ever solve this? same issue right now. at a dead end